# how to keep notification badge on

Tags: android, push-notification, badge

In android Oreo Android 8.0 supports badges on the shortcut icon.

The problem is, the spec says i need to keep the badge on even after the user deleted the notification from the notification panel.

How do I do that?

[ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) does not work on this phone.

In theory when I display this number, I do it this way:

```
   api.getUnreadNotificationCount(unreadCount -> {
            ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getApplicationContext(), unreadCount);

            NotificationCompat.Builder groupBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(CloudMessaging.this, pushNotificationModel.collapseKey == null ? getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id) : pushNotificationModel.collapseKey)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(null)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                    .setChannelId(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                    .setGroup(remoteMessage.getCollapseKey())
                    .setGroupSummary(true)
                    .setNumber(unreadCount)
                    .setSubText(unreadCount + " new updates");

            pushNotificationModel.summaryMessageId = 100;
         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                notificationManager.notify(pushNotificationModel.collapseKey, pushNotificationModel.summaryMessageId, groupBuilder.build());
            }
   });
```

and somehow `WhatsApp` is able to do it.

Comment: which company mobile are you using?

Comment: Samsung galaxy s9

Comment: boolean success = ShortcutBadger.isBadgeCounterSupported(this); write this line before applyCount method and check responce is true than your device is working  badge on.

Comment: Please read in the question that i state that ShortcutBadger does *not* support this phone, yet Whatsapp does support this phone, so there is a way, I just don't know what it is. Do you ?

Comment: i think Whatsapp is making his own badge on that why its working...and are you using third party.

Comment: @Pratik18 their badge looks exactly like all the other badges, I don't think they are making their own... and if they are, how do I make my own ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
  builder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL);
  NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, "Badger Sample",
  NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
  channel.setShowBadge(true);
  mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
 }
```

remove below line

```
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getApplicationContext(), unreadCount);
```

Comment: My problem is not the badge appearing - it is the badge disappearing when i dismiss all of the notifications from the notification pane, and I am using the channel id and setShowBadge(true)

Comment: you can set not cancel able notification. when user click on your notification after open app and clear notification than after your app badge remove.